# Gparted: move unallocated space up to root partition

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, gparted

I'v been searching around and learned that I can't just move unallocated space between partitions. I have to make it so it gets close to the partition I need to increase space. How can add this 50GB of free space to my root partition (dev/sda1)?

My unallocated space was inside the extended partition (I removed 50GB from /dev/sda5 and then removed it again from /dev/sda2).

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEiXQ.png)

PS: I was live booting.

Comment: "Moving unallocated space" is the wrong way to think about this. Unallocated space is a technical term for lack of partitions. You can't move lack of partitions. You can move partitions though.

Comment: Partitions are defined by a start sector and an end sector. By creating two partitions which have an end sector, and then a start sector, which differ by >1, you create unallocated space between partitions. In order to manipulate unallocated space in the way OP describes, GParted may be used to "move" the partitions after the desired one in order to shift the unallocated space. For instance by manipulating the "free space following", giving it a 0/low value, the last partition will be moved creating free space between sda2 and sda3. sda3 may then be moved, until finally sda1 can be resized.